# How to apply the same changes to two projects

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have two almost identical projects. The second project/app is almost the same but has ads disabled.

I need to apply a lot of changes to project 1, which means also applying them to project 2

Is there an easy way to apply the changes to project 2 without having to manually do each change again?

Comment: Moving over to Gradle would really help your situation

Comment: Try to put the common code in separate project and use it as library.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a way to refactor the two projects so they care a common codebase, and you have a configuration flag that disables the ads? That way you don't have two common code bases to maintain. I have an iOS project that is similar, and we do it with build targets in xCode.

Otherwise I think a gold old fashioned hand merge is the way to do it. Use whatever comes with your VCS of choice, or an app like BeyondCompare.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If your using Android studio, use flavour structure.

In Gradle:

```
  productFlavors{
        adds {
            applicationId "com.example.krishna.mysample.addsapp"
            version 1.1
        }

        withoutadds {
            applicationId "com.example.krishna.mysample.withoutaddapp"
            version 1.1
        }
    }
```

In folder structure In App:

```
src
  -->adds
  -->main
  -->withoutadds
```

If MainActivity is required adds then, that MainActivity is place in adds and without adds folder remaining classes are keep in main folder only. And do diffent functionality on that Activities.